# CATransform3D always becomes topmost view

Tags: ios, xcode, catransform3d

I'am transforming one UIView's layer by using CATransform3D. The problem is that I can't display other controls (which are not subviews of this transformed view) above it.

For example this code:

```
[UIView flipTransitionFromView:self.standardImageView 
toView:self.flippedImageView 
duration:1.0f 
completion:NULL];    

[self.view insertSubview:flippedCloseButton aboveSubview:flippedImageView];
```

does not work - the flippedCloseButton is always behind the flippedImageView.

`flipTransitionFromView` is a method which merely makes the said 3d transformation.

Any ideas how to solve it are highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I kinda solved it myself by modifying the view layers' zPosition:

```
self.flippedCloseButton.layer.zPosition = self.flippedImageView.layer.zPosition + 1;
```

But is it the correct way to do this?

Andrius

Comment: Are you perhaps moving the view on the z axis as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but changing the zPosition did not solve it. The zPosition is used when giving a perspective to the layer (so that it looks smaller when z is larger), but not meant forgiving a visibility sequence I believe.

I do not fully understand what is happening, but when several sublayers are present at the same "Layer level", the question "what is visible" is not well- defined. I even had that part of a layer was visible and the other part was not.

I solved this in my case  by putting the elements that have to be on top in the super layer. That ensures they are alway visible.

I am by no means a pro when it comes to Layers and animation, but in the course of educating myself, I made an App (PerspectiveTest) that explains some basics of how layer parameters and perspective work together. Might be of some help:
http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/perspectivetest/id481006743?mt=8

Regards,
Voppe